# Use Spring 3 MVC Annotation Validation with Freemarker

Tags: validation, data-binding, spring-mvc, freemarker, spring-3

I am using Spring 3 MVC Annotation Validation. I know how to do it in JSP(using `modelAttribute` property in JSP), but I don't have any clue how to apply this kind of data binding in Freemarker.

Example of JSP equivalence

```
<c:url var="addUrl" value="/admin/workerAdd" />
<form:form modelAttribute="worker" action="${addUrl}" method="post">
    <p>
 <form:label for="code" path="code">Code</form:label>
     <form:input path="code" readonly="false" />
    </p>
...
```

Example of Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/*")
public class AdminController {    
    @Autowired
    private CommonService commonService;

    /**
     * For every request for this controller, this will 
     * create a person instance for the form.
     */
    @ModelAttribute
    public Worker newRequest(@RequestParam(required=false) String id) {
        return (id != null ? commonService.getWorkerById(id) : new Worker());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/workerAdd", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String performAddUser(@Valid Worker worker, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return null;
        }

            // Create the worker here.

        return "redirect:/administration/manageUser";
    }
```

Now I want to use the same controller, but the views are written by Freemarker(ftl). The data-binding in my below freemarker doesn't work (which is understandable, since it should have different syntax). I did some research and learn about command object in FTL, but I don't get the point. I think it should be a similar attribute that tell Spring to do the binding but I still not find it yet.

```
<form id="worker" modelAttribute="worker" action="${rc.getContextUrl('/admin/workerAdd')}" method="post" >          
            <div class="Entry">
            <label for="code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value="${worker.code}" />
            </div>
```

Is there any simple way to make this annotation validation way (and the databinding as well) works with FTL? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Hoang Long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You JSP code can be rewritten in Freemarker as follows:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
...
<form id="worker" action="${rc.getContextUrl('/admin/workerAdd')}" method="post" > 
    <p>
        <label for = "code">Code</label>
        <@spring.formInput "worker.code" />
    </p> 
...
```

Note that Spring library for Freemarker doesn't have specifal element for `form`, so you need to use ordinary html `form` and prepend model attribute name to paths of individual fields.

**See also:**

- [16.4 Velocity & FreeMarker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity)

Comment: it works, thank you a lot! Do you know any other resources that offer full sample project. I'm a bit confused when reading the link

Comment: @Hoàng: No. Personally I had to read source code and tests to get it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add the following clarification to save people some time.
When reading the docs, it says that unless you override the @ModelAttribute(value=...) the bean would be accessed as "**command**" in your view.

For Freemarker (tested with 3.1M1), the default is className (eg if the Command class is named "**Change PasswordCommand**", then the bean will be bound to **changePasswordCommand** by default.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think it definitely help others:)